# How to show a marker tooltip that can overflow the map container?

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

In my map, I have to show some markers that have relatively large tooltips attached to them (a div with roughly 100x200px). The map container itself is about 350px in height, so you very often run into situations where your tooltips are cut off at the map borders.

From what I can see, the map container has `overflow: hidden;` set in its CSS, which is because of the way the tiles get shown (they move "under" the container). When I set the overflow to visible, it seems to work, but then the map floods the page.

Is there a plugin or some best practice to achieve the desired behaviour without completely changing leaflet under the hood?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution, instead of appending the tootip to the map container, append it as the last child of `document.body` then just call `getBoundingClientRect()` on the marker DOM node on hover or on click and use it to position the tootip next to your marker node. That way, your tootip won't be constrained by the size of the map container.